# call function after complete page load

Tags: javascript

I'm using a javascript in my html page.. I have been recording the time taken using the navigation API .. When I try to findout the total load time (navigationStart - loadEventEnd) I find that the loadEventEnd is 0 . But also found that the loadEventStart value is recorded .. I print these values on console inside window.onload = function() {} . . From the above stats I assume that my function is called after the load event has fired and before it has completed ..  However using onunload function gives me the result , the result cannot be viewed as it is printed in the console and unload event is triggered when moving away from the page .. Please help me find a solution .

Comment: Assuming this is just for debugging purposes, you can open another window and write the value to the other window's DOM.

Comment: Some browsers support "preserve log" in their console. Turning that on will allow you to read `onbeforeunload` messages after navigating to a new page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you're getting a value of `0` because you're printing the information *before* the page has completed loading, try the following snippet:

```
window.onload = function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        var t = performance.timing;
        console.log(t.loadEventEnd - t.responseEnd);
    }, 0);
}
```

That will make sure the numbers are printed after the page is actually ready. Got that snippet from [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webperformance/basics/). Other information from that page you might find interesting:

> Data from the API really comes to life when events are used in combination:
>
> - Network latency (): `responseEnd-fetchStart`.
> - The time taken for page load once the page is received from the server: `loadEventEnd-responseEnd`.
> - The whole process of navigation and page load: `loadEventEnd-navigationStart`.

Comment: Thanks ..that helped .. but i couldnt understand the part that how a setTimeout  with a delay of 0 milliseconds could help load the page completely

Comment: It's an interesting hack indeed, what it does is schedule the function to run later, then when the script finishes execution (and thus the page is fully loaded) the schedule will kick in and run your task right away. Remember to accept helpful answers :)

Comment: I'm using my javascript as a bookmarklet .. But this does restrict me from using more than 2000 characters in my script .. Please suggest me some alternatives

Answer (score 1):

Use the onload attribute in the  tag as follows:-

> `<body onload="methodName();">`

Try the following example for better understanding:-

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test(){
            alert("hello");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="test();">
    <h5>Simple javascript test for page load</h5>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. i hope it will also work...
Use the **window.onload** object as follows:-

```
window.onload=function(){
                  //set of javascript statments...
              }
```

or if you have any functions then use the window.onload as follows:-

```
window.onload=function_name
```

Have a look at the following example for better understanding of window.location

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = test;

        function test(){
            alert("hello");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h5>Simple javascript test for page load</h5>
</body>
</html>
```